# For all your flag design needs

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, geography, flags

> Pleased to meet you. I'm the CEO of a startup that specializes in designing flags for newly-independent countries. As an example, let me present to you the flag we designed for the proud republic of Guinefghanistance. Looks pretty, no?
>
> [image: Guinefghanistance flag]
>
> Here is a list of our ongoing projects. As you see, new nations are forming with a rapid pace and we have plenty of work in our hands.
>
> 1. Chinoland
> 2. Benimadagigeria
> 3. Guatnicaruras
> 4. Permonaprus
> 5. Tanzanidad
> 6. Indomoropore
> 7. Pakiturkmapan
> 8. Vativinceroon
> 9. Barbacublgeria

Do you think we have any future in the flag design business?

Comment: Guinefghanistance? Guinea + Afghanistan + France?

Comment: @user477343 An unlikely union, I know. Stranger things have happened!

Comment: you are a great puzzle creator, jafe ;) (too bad I have reached my daily voting limit) $\color{orange}{\bigstar}$

Comment: @user477343 You can vote for it now.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I did already ;)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Your business seems to be ...

> ... **lucrative**.

Panda, Brandon and commenters have already figured out ...

> ... what old countries make up the new ones. The flag for a new country is designed by cutting the flags of the old countries into vertical strips and then sewing one strip from each of them together in the order in which the countries' name fragments appear in the new name.
>
>  Here are [sewing patterns](https://www.countries-ofthe-world.com/flags-of-the-world.html) for the old flags.

So let's do that and we see:

> [image: Plain to see: it's lucrative]

Answer (score 12):

Here's a shot, based on PartyHatPanda's start.

Note that I'm not sure

> What you want. I'm just going to put the countries' names that have been combined.

Your flag is

> Guinea, Afghanistan, and France pushed together

1. > China and Poland
2. > Benin, Nigeria, and Madagascar
3. > Guatemala, Nicaragua, and Honduras
4. > Peru, Monaco, and Cyprus - last one by suggestion of @PartyHatPanda
5. > Tanzania and Trinidad and Tobago
6. > Indonesia, Morocco, and Singapore (credit to Panda)
7. > Pakistan, Turkmenistan, and Japan
8. > Vatican, Saint Vincent and the Grenadines, and Cameroon
9. > Barbados, Cuba, and Algeria

I think that's it!

Comment: But the "m" after "turk" - that's why I put what I did

Comment: @OmegaKrypton No, otherwise that M should not be there.

Comment: @Brandon_J, Nice, but with number four the last third I am questioning. (ROT13)Abgvpr gur raq bs gur perngrq pbhagevrf raq jvgu gur raqvat bs n erny pbhagel. Fb raqvat jvgu cehf pbhyq or fbzrguvat yvxr Plcehf?

Comment: sorry youre right

Comment: @PartyHatPanda good point will change that. thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Partial Answer describing the first:

> It is of three countries pushed together, Guinea, Afghanistan, and France in that order. Similarly, it has the first third of the Guinean flag, the middle third of the Afghanistan Flag, and the last third of the French flag (from left to right) all pushed together.

6 maybe:

> Indonesia, Morocco, and Singapore; Indonesia's and Singapore's flags are both split horizontally through the middle, so it could be the red top half from Indonesia's flag, the Green Star in the middle from Morocco's flag, and the white bottom half of Singapore's flag.

Comment: gonna ruin your 1k rep with a +1...

Comment: Oh nooooooo, I'm so sad! ;)